# Firewall restricting Django Server

Tags: django, windows

I am running django server on my local ip (192.168.86.122:8000) but the windows firewall seems to block the connection.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network facing ports are probably blocked.

Either use localhost instead:
`py manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

Or allow port 8000 on your windows firewall:
`netsh firewall add portopening TCP 8000 "Django Dev Server"`